# Understand where compilation time is taken when using GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, g++

I have a project that makes massive use of templates. Recently the compilation time rose quite abruptly. I wonder if there's a way for seeing what classes / lines require the most time to be compiled by `g++`.

Here is some output from [-ftime-report](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#index-ftime-report):

```
Execution times (seconds)
 TOTAL                 :   0.30             0.05             0.37               9119 kB

Execution times (seconds)
 garbage collection    :   0.91 ( 6%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.92 ( 5%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 callgraph construction:   0.23 ( 2%) usr   0.11 ( 3%) sys   0.37 ( 2%) wall   10652 kB ( 1%) ggc
 callgraph optimization:   0.18 ( 1%) usr   0.12 ( 3%) sys   0.28 ( 2%) wall   11906 kB ( 2%) ggc
 varpool construction  :   0.04 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.08 ( 0%) wall    6984 kB ( 1%) ggc
 cfg construction      :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall     644 kB ( 0%) ggc
 cfg cleanup           :   0.05 ( 0%) usr   0.02 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall       7 kB ( 0%) ggc
 trivially dead code   :   0.05 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.12 ( 1%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df scan insns         :   0.37 ( 3%) usr   0.03 ( 1%) sys   0.43 ( 2%) wall     677 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df live regs          :   0.07 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 df reg dead/unused notes:   0.08 ( 1%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.08 ( 0%) wall    2755 kB ( 0%) ggc
 register information  :   0.05 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 alias analysis        :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall     878 kB ( 0%) ggc
 rebuild jump labels   :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 preprocessing         :   0.19 ( 1%) usr   0.44 (11%) sys   0.68 ( 4%) wall    5284 kB ( 1%) ggc
 parser                :   3.94 (28%) usr   1.43 (35%) sys   4.94 (27%) wall  355964 kB (48%) ggc
 name lookup           :   1.35 ( 9%) usr   0.88 (21%) sys   2.76 (15%) wall   64919 kB ( 9%) ggc
 inline heuristics     :   0.14 ( 1%) usr   0.03 ( 1%) sys   0.14 ( 1%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 integration           :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall      20 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree gimplify         :   0.31 ( 2%) usr   0.07 ( 2%) sys   0.28 ( 2%) wall   24598 kB ( 3%) ggc
 tree eh               :   0.07 ( 0%) usr   0.02 ( 0%) sys   0.11 ( 1%) wall    7267 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree CFG construction :   0.04 ( 0%) usr   0.04 ( 1%) sys   0.11 ( 1%) wall   15754 kB ( 2%) ggc
 tree CFG cleanup      :   0.12 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 ( 0%) wall       3 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree find ref. vars   :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall     963 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree PHI insertion    :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall     351 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree SSA rewrite      :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.01 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall    4078 kB ( 1%) ggc
 tree SSA other        :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.06 ( 1%) sys   0.12 ( 1%) wall    1504 kB ( 0%) ggc
 tree operand scan     :   0.04 ( 0%) usr   0.02 ( 0%) sys   0.08 ( 0%) wall   10781 kB ( 1%) ggc
 dominance computation :   0.15 ( 1%) usr   0.04 ( 1%) sys   0.15 ( 1%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 out of ssa            :   0.09 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.02 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 expand vars           :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 0%) wall    1840 kB ( 0%) ggc
 expand                :   0.45 ( 3%) usr   0.04 ( 1%) sys   0.59 ( 3%) wall   37695 kB ( 5%) ggc
 post expand cleanups  :   0.08 ( 1%) usr   0.02 ( 0%) sys   0.06 ( 0%) wall    4542 kB ( 1%) ggc
 varconst              :   0.15 ( 1%) usr   0.03 ( 1%) sys   0.12 ( 1%) wall    3595 kB ( 0%) ggc
 jump                  :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.04 ( 0%) wall    1904 kB ( 0%) ggc
 mode switching        :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 integrated RA         :   1.33 ( 9%) usr   0.09 ( 2%) sys   1.49 ( 8%) wall   18163 kB ( 2%) ggc
 reload                :   0.60 ( 4%) usr   0.10 ( 2%) sys   0.62 ( 3%) wall    8668 kB ( 1%) ggc
 thread pro- & epilogue:   0.17 ( 1%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.20 ( 1%) wall   11884 kB ( 2%) ggc
 reg stack             :   0.02 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 final                 :   0.71 ( 5%) usr   0.10 ( 2%) sys   0.84 ( 5%) wall    6251 kB ( 1%) ggc
 symout                :   1.10 ( 8%) usr   0.16 ( 4%) sys   1.19 ( 6%) wall  100954 kB (14%) ggc
 uninit var analysis   :   0.03 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 early local passes    :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 rest of compilation   :   0.49 ( 3%) usr   0.06 ( 1%) sys   0.76 ( 4%) wall   19252 kB ( 3%) ggc
 unaccounted todo      :   0.43 ( 3%) usr   0.09 ( 2%) sys   0.55 ( 3%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 TOTAL                 :  14.26             4.11            18.52             742072 kB
```

Comment: You're going need to provide much more information than that. It's hard for us to help without anything to look at.

Comment: You could try compiling different revisions and see when the increase in time occurs; then look at what changes occurred in that revision to hopefully give you some insight.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072454/how-do-i-find-out-why-g-takes-a-very-long-time-on-a-particular-file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging GCC Compile Times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390532/debugging-gcc-compile-times)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Steven Watanabe's template profiler may help you get a per class/function instantiation count.

See *[Debugging GCC Compile Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390532/debugging-gcc-compile-times/6390569#6390569)* for an actual link to this tool.

Comment: Nowadays, one can also use the better clang 9 -ftime-trace option

Answer (score 7):

When I read that you have made massive use of templates in your project, my first suspicion was template instantiation, and after seeing the following information, my suspicion became stronger:

```
parser       : ... (27%) wall 355964 kB (48%) ggc
name lookup  : ... (15%) wall 64919 kB ( 9%) ggc
```

Since I cannot see the code (as you have not posted it), so I can only suspect. My second suspicion is, you have not used *explicit* instantiation of the templates for the *known* types (which you will most certainly use), instead you depend on *implicit* instantiation **and** you are using templates from lots of`.cpp` file. If so, then that could be the major problem, because *implicit* instantiation causes *same* templates to be instantiated *many* times, once for each translation unit. So if you have `M` templates and you are using it from `N` translation units (`.cpp`), then there will be `M * N` instantiations, instead of just `M` instantiations.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the case, same template classes instantiated in many .cpp files. I would try to find out the template classes that require the most time, and modify them.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no such compilation switch does exist.

A more manual method can be to split between preprocessing and compilation (*gcc [-E](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-E)*, then *gcc [-c](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-c)* on preprocessed file) to guess where time is spent.

Another solution is to instrument your build environment to have compilation time per file. Note that I can only recommend to set up [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) to track such evolutions early (as soon as it pops up, you detect it without having to dig in the past what introduced the jump).

As a rule of thumb, you can check that only relevant headers are included (try to remove some) or could switch to precompiled headers.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I already have an idea of the files that give the longest compilation times.And, as you point out, those are the ones which include most of the headers.
I tried with precompiled headers, but got not so higher speed improvement (still I do not get why). only ccache gave me a speed improvement

Comment: with -Q I get that most of the time is spent on the parser. But I have no idea of what this could mean in term of code to be suspicious of.

Comment: The option `-ftime-report` exists on Mac OS X with `/usr/bin/gcc` -- `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)`.  The fuller report seems to come from `/usr/bin/clang` -- `Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)`.  It may be an option to `clang`, or it may just be an option in more recent versions of GCC.

Comment: thank you, -ftime-report exists in g++, but it gives just what you see in the post