# Make Gcc specify which templates are taking the longest

Tags: c++, optimization, compilation, g++, profiling

Gcc can profile itself, and with this you can see which part of the compilation process takes the longest.

A sample output:

```
Time variable                                   usr           sys          wall               GGC
 phase setup                        :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)    1369 kB (  0%)
 phase parsing                      :   5.76 ( 72%)   2.38 ( 87%)   9.27 ( 78%)  554966 kB ( 80%)
 phase lang. deferred               :   0.50 (  6%)   0.16 (  6%)   0.67 (  6%)   62109 kB (  9%)
 phase opt and generate             :   1.58 ( 20%)   0.18 (  7%)   1.78 ( 15%)   66512 kB ( 10%)
 phase last asm                     :   0.14 (  2%)   0.02 (  1%)   0.15 (  1%)    4587 kB (  1%)
 phase finalize                     :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)       0 kB (  0%)
 |name lookup                       :   0.90 ( 11%)   0.36 ( 13%)   1.71 ( 14%)   17506 kB (  3%)
 |overload resolution               :   0.78 ( 10%)   0.24 (  9%)   1.17 ( 10%)   68510 kB ( 10%)
 garbage collection                 :   0.58 (  7%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.79 (  7%)       0 kB (  0%)
 dump files                         :   0.07 (  1%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)       0 kB (  0%)
 callgraph construction             :   0.31 (  4%)   0.02 (  1%)   0.29 (  2%)   26559 kB (  4%)
 callgraph optimization             :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.05 (  0%)      10 kB (  0%)
 ipa function summary               :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)     412 kB (  0%)
 ipa inlining heuristics            :   0.01 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)     282 kB (  0%)
 ipa pure const                     :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)      26 kB (  0%)
 cfg cleanup                        :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)       1 kB (  0%)
 trivially dead code                :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)       2 kB (  0%)
 df scan insns                      :   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)       2 kB (  0%)
 df live regs                       :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)      24 kB (  0%)
 df reg dead/unused notes           :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)     172 kB (  0%)
 register information               :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)       0 kB (  0%)
 alias stmt walking                 :   0.03 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)     241 kB (  0%)
 rebuild jump labels                :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)       0 kB (  0%)
 preprocessing                      :   0.66 (  8%)   0.61 ( 22%)   1.53 ( 13%)   45104 kB (  7%)
 parser (global)                    :   0.78 ( 10%)   0.59 ( 22%)   1.47 ( 12%)  107059 kB ( 16%)
 parser struct body                 :   0.77 ( 10%)   0.18 (  7%)   1.00 (  8%)   64460 kB (  9%)
 parser enumerator list             :   0.05 (  1%)   0.02 (  1%)   0.07 (  1%)    2628 kB (  0%)
 parser function body               :   0.20 (  3%)   0.10 (  4%)   0.35 (  3%)    9952 kB (  1%)
 parser inl. func. body             :   0.35 (  4%)   0.19 (  7%)   0.62 (  5%)   25224 kB (  4%)
 parser inl. meth. body             :   1.20 ( 15%)   0.28 ( 10%)   1.49 ( 13%)  110313 kB ( 16%)
 template instantiation             :   1.60 ( 20%)   0.48 ( 18%)   2.55 ( 21%)  172942 kB ( 25%)
 constant expression evaluation     :   0.10 (  1%)   0.05 (  2%)   0.08 (  1%)    1091 kB (  0%)
 early inlining heuristics          :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)     292 kB (  0%)
 inline parameters                  :   0.01 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)    2592 kB (  0%)
 integration                        :   0.14 (  2%)   0.08 (  3%)   0.11 (  1%)    8382 kB (  1%)
 tree gimplify                      :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)    3581 kB (  1%)
 tree eh                            :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)     373 kB (  0%)
 tree CFG construction              :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)    1628 kB (  0%)
 tree CFG cleanup                   :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)      10 kB (  0%)
 tree SSA other                     :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)     183 kB (  0%)
 tree SSA incremental               :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)     100 kB (  0%)
 tree operand scan                  :   0.07 (  1%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.07 (  1%)    2924 kB (  0%)
 tree CCP                           :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)     118 kB (  0%)
 tree FRE                           :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)     363 kB (  0%)
 tree forward propagate             :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.04 (  0%)     112 kB (  0%)
 tree aggressive DCE                :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)     152 kB (  0%)
 tree DSE                           :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)      28 kB (  0%)
 PHI merge                          :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)       4 kB (  0%)
 dominance computation              :   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)       0 kB (  0%)
 expand vars                        :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)     153 kB (  0%)
 expand                             :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)    3103 kB (  0%)
 varconst                           :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)       6 kB (  0%)
 forward prop                       :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)     176 kB (  0%)
 CSE                                :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)      15 kB (  0%)
 dead store elim1                   :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)     117 kB (  0%)
 dead store elim2                   :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)     149 kB (  0%)
 loop init                          :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)     647 kB (  0%)
 branch prediction                  :   0.01 (  0%)   0.02 (  1%)   0.02 (  0%)     229 kB (  0%)
 combiner                           :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)      96 kB (  0%)
 integrated RA                      :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)    1862 kB (  0%)
 LRA non-specific                   :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)      62 kB (  0%)
 LRA create live ranges             :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)      10 kB (  0%)
 reload CSE regs                    :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)     101 kB (  0%)
 thread pro- & epilogue             :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)     131 kB (  0%)
 hard reg cprop                     :   0.01 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)       8 kB (  0%)
 machine dep reorg                  :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)       7 kB (  0%)
 reg stack                          :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)       0 kB (  0%)
 final                              :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)    1906 kB (  0%)
 symout                             :   0.44 (  6%)   0.07 (  3%)   0.49 (  4%)   87737 kB ( 13%)
 variable tracking                  :   0.02 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)     901 kB (  0%)
 var-tracking dataflow              :   0.08 (  1%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.08 (  1%)      34 kB (  0%)
 var-tracking emit                  :   0.03 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)    1180 kB (  0%)
 initialize rtl                     :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)      12 kB (  0%)
 rest of compilation                :   0.05 (  1%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  0%)     289 kB (  0%)
 remove unused locals               :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  0%)       1 kB (  0%)
 address taken                      :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  0%)       0 kB (  0%)
 TOTAL                              :   7.98          2.74         11.90         689554 kB
```

I would like to know other things however. For example which files are taking the longest to compile? Which functions. And in particular, it seems my compilation bottleneck is template instantiation. I would like to know which templates exactly are taking the longest.

I tried looking this up but all I find is documentation on how to generate the above table.

The table is generated by adding `-ftime-report` to the g++ flags.

Comment: You pass `-ftime-report` to g++.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21836167/485343

Comment: I seem to need some kind of account to access the "tool"

Comment: No, simply Boost moved from SVN to Git and that tool didn't "make" it. You might want to just google `TEMPLATE_PROFILE_ENTER` instead.