# Is there a way to profile the compilation of a single C++ compilation unit?

Tags: c++, compilation, profiling

I am currently working on a C++ library where each individual compilation unit is taking tens of seconds to compile using gcc, likely due to extensive use of header-only libraries.  Is there some method or tool to tell exactly what steps of the compilation process and/or which specific includes are causing the bunk of the compilation time?

Comment: If the header-only libraries are some external libraries, you could use [Precomplied Header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header) technic to reduce compilation time.

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559818/profiling-the-c-compilation-process