# Differences between C++ and Java compilation process

Tags: java, c++

I have high level idea on the differences between C++ and Java compilation. But, I want to really understand and dive deep. can you suggest any references or blogs ?

Comment: There are far more differences than commonalities.

Comment: Is there some specific aspect you're interested in? This question is too broad as it stands right now.

Comment: Compilation or linking?  The difference in compilation just means different grammars, ASTs, and code generation.  It's the linking and loading that gets really interesting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference bettwen C++ and Java compilation process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095277/difference-bettwen-c-and-java-compilation-process)

Comment: @Bala, You have more than 30 questions without an accepted answer. Perhaps you can follow up on more answers so they can be accepted.

Comment: I've noticed that the possible duplicate was posted by @Bala himself. This question was also closed as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe [this](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigmil/RevEng/ch02.html) can bring some light on the subject

Java:

[image]

C++:

[image]