# What's best value for make -j

Tags: makefile, compilation

What's the best value of -j switch?

I usually set this up to the number of CPU/Cores available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've always seen the number of cores available plus 1 as the recommended value

Comment: The idea behind the +1 being that it helps keep the processor(s) doing something while they're waiting on disk I/O for the next source file.

Comment: See [MAKEOPTS=”-j${core} +1″ is NOT the best optimization](https://blogs.gentoo.org/ago/2013/01/14/makeopts-jcore-1-is-not-the-best-optimization/)

Comment: what if I am using distcc? still then it depends on no of core on the host where it is triggered or sum of all in the distcc hosts?

Answer (score 5):

Just measure.

Start with the number of cores. And then add one until you feel that you get diminishing returns.

Comment: +1 Experiment is the only real way to go here. I've written a fair amount of multi-threaded code that was I/O bound, and you can normally increase  the number of threads well over the number of processors and still get performance increases. Then at some point the performance drops off , often quite dramatically.

Comment: I'm kind of torn here, whether this is a good idea or not. At some point, you get increased performance only because the threads take up a bigger timeslice. That's not a very good idea. Rather, if the build process is that important, one should rather use less threads and raise the `nice`'ness level.

Comment: @Mads: What I'm talking about here is that a build process can be doing lots of disk access.  A number of threads can quickly be blocked waiting for the disk, meanwhile the others (one per core) can be doing actual compiling.

Comment: Note that on some hosts and with some codebases (e.g. C++ with lots of fancy templates) memory exhaustion can be an issue.  If you increase the `-j` count enough that your computer runs out of RAM and starts swapping, it's going to slow your compiles down by a lot :)