# Why Compilation Speed Differs a lot in C++ and C#?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does C++ compilation take so long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318398/why-does-c-compilation-take-so-long)

Coming from C# background, I can't help but notice that the speed of compilation  for C++ and C# code differs a lot-- C# is very fast to compile, but C++ is comparatively slow-- very slow, in fact.

Why is this so?

Comment: Ah, it is a dupe. But I can't see that in question suggestion when I typed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two big reasons:

1. C++ has to go and `#include` and parse all the header files (which means reading text files and interpreting them -- including templates -- and then expanding them right into your code) whereas C# uses pre-compiled information in the assembly DLLs.
2. The potential C++ optimizations are *way* more far-reaching than the C# optimizations; they easily blow C# out of the water. The C# compiler never inlines a function call (that's the Just-In-Time compiler's job to do in the CLR), but C++ compilers frequently do that, and much more. The C++ compiler also has to do the JIT's compiler for the *entire* program at *compile* time (and then some!), so it's definitely slower.

I'd say that the *biggest* culprit is optimizations -- try turning off all optimizations in your compiler, and noticing the speedup.