# Is g++ normally much slower than gcc when compiling?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, g++

I've been coding with plain C for the last few months because of our university curriculum. The programs I write are quite small and very not-resource-demanding. As a result, compiling with gcc has always been an almost instantaneous process (40ms on my "biggest" program so far).

Recently though, I enrolled in a local competition, for which C++ is apparently the norm, and so I started practicing. Despite my programs still being extremely small (not even half a kB), I noticed that compiling with g++ has consistently been almost like a 0.2s pause, followed by the instantaneous compilation I was used to with gcc.

Here's the code I'm currently testing it on:

```cpp
//#include <bits/stdc++.h> // I commented this out thinking that maybe the problem was due to too many header files being included
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>

using namespace std; // I know this is kind of a bad practice but I've been told it's recommended in competitions for ease of writing

int mex(vector<int> arr, vector<int> subarr) {
    int min = INT_MAX;

    for (auto i : arr) {
        // If i doesn't exist in subarr
        if (find(subarr.begin(), subarr.end(), i) == subarr.end()) {
            if (i < min) {
                min = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return min;
}

int main () {
    vector<int> a = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    vector<int> suba = {0, 1,3,4};

    cout << mex(a, suba) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles in 240ms.
Here's g++'s `ftime-report`:

```
Time variable                                   usr           sys          wall           GGC
 phase setup                        :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)  1562k (  2%)
 phase parsing                      :   0.16 ( 84%)   0.13 ( 87%)   0.29 ( 85%)    60M ( 83%)
 phase lang. deferred               :   0.01 (  5%)   0.01 (  7%)   0.02 (  6%)  5818k (  8%)
 phase opt and generate             :   0.02 ( 11%)   0.01 (  7%)   0.03 (  9%)  5468k (  7%)
 |name lookup                       :   0.05 ( 26%)   0.02 ( 13%)   0.03 (  9%)  2550k (  3%)
 |overload resolution               :   0.01 (  5%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.02 (  6%)  6891k (  9%)
 callgraph construction             :   0.01 (  5%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  3%)  1448k (  2%)
 df scan insns                      :   0.01 (  5%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)  4128  (  0%)
 preprocessing                      :   0.01 (  5%)   0.05 ( 33%)   0.05 ( 15%)  1805k (  2%)
 parser (global)                    :   0.03 ( 16%)   0.02 ( 13%)   0.07 ( 21%)    16M ( 23%)
 parser struct body                 :   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 ( 20%)   0.03 (  9%)    11M ( 15%)
 parser function body               :   0.03 ( 16%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  9%)  3231k (  4%)
 parser inl. func. body             :   0.01 (  5%)   0.02 ( 13%)   0.01 (  3%)  1474k (  2%)
 parser inl. meth. body             :   0.01 (  5%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.03 (  9%)  5790k (  8%)
 template instantiation             :   0.07 ( 37%)   0.02 ( 13%)   0.08 ( 24%)    19M ( 27%)
 constant expression evaluation     :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  3%)    85k (  0%)
 expand                             :   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  7%)   0.00 (  0%)   367k (  0%)
 integrated RA                      :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)  2092k (  3%)
 LRA non-specific                   :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  3%)    14k (  0%)
 symout                             :   0.01 (  5%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)  6907k (  9%)
 rest of compilation                :   0.00 (  0%)   0.00 (  0%)   0.01 (  3%)   212k (  0%)
 TOTAL                              :   0.19          0.15          0.34           73M
```

I'm using gcc and g++ versions 11.4.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Is this a normal occurrence? Is g++ normally this noticeably slower than gcc? Or is there an underlying issue on my computer?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've played with this, but IIRC, c++ compilation was mostly bottlenecked by the huge include files of the STL, and not that much by C++ being that much slower (though it was a bit slower, understandably).

Comment: An average C++ include header adds much much more to compile time than an average POSIX/standard-C include. C headers can slow down compilation too, especially if they contain a lot of inline functions (macros are much faster to parse than inline functions). But the POSIX/standard-C headers are typically just a few typedefs and declarations with an occasional #define.

Comment: You can probably speed up your local compilation by including all your standard headers via a separate file as a [precompiled header](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html). You can still make your code submittable by using some macro that you define locally. If it's not defined, don't use the precompiled header and instead include everything inline in the main source file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is pretty common from my experience as C++ has many features and more complicated syntax.

If your code doesn't use any C++ features the compile time may be almost identical, but using C++ introduces many more checks and logic that adds to the complexity of the process.

You can find a more detailed explaination for the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318398/why-does-c-compilation-take-so-long)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal . The C++ language is far more complicated than the C language, and there's more going on in the standard headers.

Enterprise-level projects can take hours to build, so be very glad yours is only taking 0.2 seconds !

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, C should have an edge in parsing speed due to its having an almost context-free grammar, unlike C++.
Practically, the parsing speeds are very similar (with C++ being only a few % slower) and the real issue is big (bloated) headers with many inline functions in the STL.

C compilations can get slowed down by headers with many inline functions too  (less so by macros), but practically they don't have them as much, at least the common ones don't.

On Linux you can basically include all of posix headers at once at a compiletime cost of a few tens of ms (impereceptible to a human) for all of them together. Compared to that, a single STL header can easily add hundreds of ms to a single file's compile time (noticable lag).

Here's a little bash script with some insight (creates/clobbers files in the current directory!!):

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
for i in {0..1000}; do echo "int f$i(void){return $i;}"; done > funcs.c
for i in {0..1000}; do echo "static inline int i$i(void){return $i;}"; done > inls.c
for i in {0..1000}; do echo "#define M$i() $i"; done > macs.c
echo " " > empty.c
echo "#include <vector>" > incl_vector.cc
echo "#include <string>" > incl_string.cc
echo "#include <iostream>" > incl_iostream.cc
echo "#include <string.h>" > incl_string.c
echo "#include <stdio.h>" > incl_stdio.c


TIMEFORMAT=%Rs
: ${CC:=gcc}
set -x
time $CC -xc -Os empty.c -c
time $CC -xc -Os funcs.c -c
time $CC -xc -Os inls.c -c
time $CC -xc -Os macs.c -c
time $CC -xc -Os incl_string.c -c
time $CC -xc -Os incl_stdio.c -c

time $CC -xc++ -Os empty.c -c
time $CC -xc++ -Os funcs.c -c
time $CC -xc++ -Os inls.c -c
time $CC -xc++ -Os macs.c -c
time $CC -xc++ -Os incl_vector.cc -c
time $CC -xc++ -Os incl_string.cc -c
time $CC -xc++ -Os incl_iostream.cc -c
```

I'm getting (older machine (Sandy Bridge i7) with gcc-13):

```
+ gcc -xc -Os empty.c -c
0.015s
+ gcc -xc -Os funcs.c -c
0.808s
+ gcc -xc -Os inls.c -c
0.031s
+ gcc -xc -Os macs.c -c
0.015s
+ gcc -xc -Os incl_string.c -c
0.017s
+ gcc -xc -Os incl_stdio.c -c
0.020s
+ gcc -xc++ -Os empty.c -c
0.015s
+ gcc -xc++ -Os funcs.c -c
0.860s
+ gcc -xc++ -Os inls.c -c
0.041s
+ gcc -xc++ -Os macs.c -c
0.016s
+ gcc -xc++ -Os incl_vector.cc -c
0.188s
+ gcc -xc++ -Os incl_string.cc -c
0.290s
+ gcc -xc++ -Os incl_iostream.cc -c
0.408s
```

and very similar numbers and relative differences for clang.